# rails application deployment nginx, unicorn,capistrano socket error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

Hi I am deploying rails application to digital ocean VPS, I have followed https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha this blog , all things done well, but now the browser shows only

#### a blank white page

In nginx log file it shows

```
   invalid host in upstream "/tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testvpsdo:2
```

What causes the error?,

this is my nginx.conf file

```
upstream unicorn {
 server unix:/tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
 listen 80 default_server deferred;
 # server_name example.com;
 root /home/navin/apps/testvpsdo/current/public;

location ^~ /assets/ {
gzip_static on;
expires max;
add_header Cache-Control public;
}

 try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
 location @unicorn {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 20M;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: looks like problem in `.conf` what return `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx configtest` or `sudo service nginx configtest` on remote server? and show full `testvpsdo.conf`

Comment: The configtest returns OK , and my conf file is

Comment: did you solve the issue? I'd be interested in knowing how.